# Undefined Symbols error when integrating Localytics iOS SDK via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, localytics

When integrating the Localytics iOS SDK via Cocoapods, I get the following errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Localytics", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>         objc-class-ref in CrashReporter.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Either you're missing a file when linking or there's a problem with the architecture.  Assuming "Localytics" is in a library, does the library support arm64?

Comment: @PhillipMills, 'Localytics' is in a library & it is supporting arm64 architecture.

Comment: If that's true, you might want to look at the link command that's being executed when your app builds and see whether the library has the right name and path.

Comment: 'Localytics' is not listed in the build phases > Link binary with libraries. but libPods.a is listed. Is it sufficient ? I am new to Cocoapods.

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?